# How could I send the user an e-mail in ASP.NET when there is only 1 day left till an event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm making an appointment scheduler. I want my system to send the user an e-mail when the upcoming event is tomorrow. I'm storing every appointment in an SQL database.

I don't know how to check continuously if the date is within a day instead of only checking it once I load the View that lists these appointments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use existing scheduling engines such as [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire), [Quartz.NET](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet) or similar

That way you can make recurring job that triggers once a day, checks for appointments and then send an email.